# I tried to npm start my React project but it is getting some errors

Tags: reactjs, npm

I started project using `npm start` but I am getting some errors:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at handleParseError (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:434:10)
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:466:5
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:327:12
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:386:16)
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:418:10
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:293:13
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /home/stinson/Desktop/React_Projects/my-app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.13.0
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I was expecting to start the server and render my React project but got this error and server stopped automatically. May be due to outdated packages or unsupported. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps

```
run npm install command
run npm audit fix --force command
try to start server
```